# Error trying to decode a non urlencoded string error on GAE but not on local dev environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, urlfetch, flask-oauthlib

I am using Flask-OAuthlib and it works fine in my local development environment but as soon as I deploy the code to the live GAE environment I get the following error:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~xxxx/test-20141215.381476653039842303/lib/oauthlib/common.py", line 129, in urldecode
    raise ValueError(error % (set(query) - urlencoded, query))
ValueError: Error trying to decode a non urlencoded string. Found invalid characters: set([u'!']) in the string:
```

Using that same password which includes the ! character works fine locally, I don't understand what the issue is when the app is deployed.

I'm using Python 2.7.6 locally.

For the URL request I'm using:
`uri = add_params_to_uri(url, params)` which is part of oauthlib.common

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this specific issue is to edit oauthlib/common.py line 110:

Change:

```
urlencoded = set(always_safe) | set('=&;%+~,*@')
```

To:

```
urlencoded = set(always_safe) | set('=&;%+~,*@!')
```

And then the ! character is accepted on the GAE live environment as well.

Comment: If you this that the original library should be improved you can make a pull request https://github.com/idan/oauthlib/blob/master/oauthlib/common.py#L110